# Java Semaphore tryAcquire does not honor timeout when under high load

Tags: java, semaphore

In our code, we call `Semaphore.tryAcquire(...)` with a timeout value. Under heavy load, the semaphore `tryAcquire` doesn't timeout as per the given timeout value and hence lot of threads will be STUCK here.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Stacktrace:

```
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226) 
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(Ab 
    stractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1033) 
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(A 
    bstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326) 
    java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.tryAcquire(Semaphore.java:414)
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: All timers are elastic under heavy load. Did it *ever* timeout, after a longer period, or just block forever?

Comment: it was blocked for ever

Comment: did you figure out the issue ? Even we are facing similar issue where some threads might have been locked forever.